# Computer wont start unless started "cold"

Tags: motherboard, hardware-failure, sleep

If I leave my computer off for long enough, it start's without a problem.

However, when waking from sleep or powering on after having recently been running:

1. It powers on (LEDs normal) for a couple seconds then off then on (LEDs indicate sleep/hibernation) without waking the monitor.
2. If I subsequently turn it off and on it will NOT crash as in (1) but will stay on without display output (LEDs indicate hibernation).
3. It will keep doing (2) until I leave it long enough and then it will starts without a problem.
4. The length of time it has to be left powered off has been steady increasing from about 15 minutes to about +6 hours.
5. The longer the computer has previously been running the longer the standby time, to the point where I have to be careful to turn my computer of early enough in the evening to get to start the next morning.
6. Restarting has never caused a problem.

I would be grateful if there's any hack that will discharge some possible static electricity, and get my computer to turn on in the morning.

Comment: "waking from sleep or powering on after having recently been running:"   Since it starts when cold, this suggests a temperature condition on the motherboard (including CPU) that is causing an intermittent fault on the board.

Comment: Sounds like a PSU or motherboard problem

Comment: Sounds like Windows.

Comment: Windows 10 is very reliable and does not normally vary on a cold start or warm restart in terms of things going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a power supply issue (confirmed by the technician who tested it).

I upgraded the PSU and now the problem's gone.